# getting traffic incidents - Bing geo box

Tags: geolocation, geo, bing

I am having issues getting Perth, Western Australia traffic incidents.

Perth GEO location is -31.973894615810956~115.85279846191405

Now according to Bing I need to create a box. But how do I create a box when I only have the above details?

In their example they have

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Traffic/Incidents/37,-105,45,-94?key=YourBingMapsKey
```

However they don't show what this area is covering, or how they made it.

Answer (score 0):

its a bbox from Colorado to Minnesota (I just put it on the map)

for Perth , you can select Left Bottom and Right Top coordinates and add it to the request

http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Traffic/Incidents/-32.24261071903905,115.73831563321075,31.64070863452504,116.03151324837162?key=YourBingMapsKey